# Winding number integral/index in plane

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-topology, vector-analysis, winding-number

Let $B(x_0,y_0)$ be an open unit disk.  Assume that $F(x,y)=(f_1 (x,y),f_2 (x,y)):\overline{B(x_0,y_0)}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ is a diffeomorphism. Assume also that $F(x,y) \ne (s_0,t_0) $, for all $(x,y)\in \partial B(x_0,y_0)$.

What is the **elementary** way to evaluate the following result?

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\partial B(x_0,y_0)}\frac{(f_1-s_0) df_2-(f_2-t_0)df_1}{(f_1-s_0) ^2+(f_2-t_0) ^2}=sign \det F'(x_0,y_0)=±1. $$

Can that be shown by using Green's theorem and then change of variables formula? Since $F$ is a diffeomorphism, due to inverse function theorem $\det F'(x,y) \ne 0$, for all $(x,y) \in B(x_0,y_0)$, and by Jordan curve theorem $F(\partial B(x_0,y_0))$ is a Jordan curve. Therefore inner domain is simply connected and we can use Green's theorem. But I'm not sure how to calculate that integral.

Comment: As you're probably aware, if
$$
\omega = \frac{x_{1}\, dx_{2} - x_{2}\, dx_{1}}{2\pi(x_{1}^{2} + x_{2}^{2})},
$$
(formally, $d\theta/(2\pi)$ on $\mathbf{R}^{2}\setminus\{(0,0)\}$), then your integral is
$$
\int_{\partial B(x_{0}, y_{0})} F^{*}\omega
  = \int_{F(\partial B(x_{0}, y_{0}))} \omega,
$$
a winding number, which can be $0$ (by Green's theorem, for example) if $F(\partial B)$ doesn't wind around the origin. In your integrand, do you mean "$f_{i} - f_{i}(x_{0},y_{0})$" instead of "$f_{i}$" (and "$F(x,y) \neq (0,0)$" is spurious)?

Comment: Thanks! It was a typo. But what is the elementary/naked way to show that pullback substitution? One needs change of variables formula?

Comment: An hour ago it was just false in certain cases; now it doesn't make sense anymore.

Comment: @Blatter: Thank you for your laconic comment. But if you have same relevant advices, please tell me. I belive that you do know what I'm trying to ask; winding number of a diffeomorphism with respect to a unit circle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $B$ is a disk with center ${\bf z}_0$ in the $(x,y)$-plane,  that
$$f:\quad \bar B\to{\Bbb R}^2, \qquad (x,y)\to(u,v):=\bigl(f_1(x,y),f_2(x,y)\bigr)$$
is a diffeomorphism, and that ${\bf 0}\notin f(\partial B)$.   Then
$$N:={1\over2\pi}\int_{\partial B}{f_1\>df_2-f_2\>df_1\over f_1^2+f_2^2}=
\left\{\eqalign{{\rm sgn}\bigl(J_f({\bf z}_0)\bigr)&\qquad\bigl({\bf 0}\in f(B)\bigr)\cr
0\qquad&\qquad\bigl({\bf 0}\notin f(B)\bigr) \cr}\right.$$
*Proof.* Consider the vector field
$${\bf A}(u,v):=\left({-v\over u^2+v^2}, \>{u\over u^2+v^2}\right)=\nabla\arg(u,v)$$
 in the punctured $(u,v)$-plane. I claim that 
 $$N={1\over2\pi}\int_{f(\partial B)}{\bf A}\cdot d{\bf w}\ .\tag{1}$$
 *Subproof.*  Let $$t\mapsto\bigl(x(t),y(t)\bigr)\qquad(0\leq t\leq T)$$ be a parametrization of $\partial B$. Then
 $$t\mapsto {\bf w}(t):=\bigl(f_1\bigl(x(t),y(t)\bigr), f_2\bigl(x(t),y(t)\bigr)\bigr)\qquad (0\leq t\leq T)$$
 is a parametrization of $f(\partial B)$. It follows that
 $$\eqalign{&\int_{f(\partial B)}{\bf A}\cdot d{\bf w}
 =\int_0^T\left({-f_2\over f_1^2+f_2^2}\bigg|_{{\bf w}(t)}\dot u(t)+ {f_1\over f_1^2+f_2^2}\bigg|_{{\bf w}(t)}\dot v(t) \right)\ dt\cr
 &=\int_0^T \left({-f_2\over f_1^2+f_2^2}\bigl(f_{1.1}\dot x(t)+f_{1.2}\dot y(t)\bigr)+
  {f_1\over f_1^2+f_2^2}\bigl(f_{2.1}\dot x(t)+f_{2.2}\dot y(t)\bigr)\right)\>dt \cr
  &=\int_{\partial B}{f_1\>df_2-f_2\>df_1\over f_1^2+f_2^2}\quad.\qquad\square\cr}$$
 Note that
 $${\rm curl}\>{\bf A}(u,v)\equiv0\ .$$
When ${\bf 0}\notin f(B)$ we can apply Green's theorem in $(1)$ and obtain
$$N={1\over2\pi}\int_{f(\partial B)}{\bf A}\cdot d{\bf w}={1\over2\pi}\int_{f(B)}{\rm curl}\>{\bf A}(u,v)\>{\rm d}(u,v)=0\ .$$
When ${\bf 0}=f({\bf p})\in f(B)$ we  introduce $B':=B\setminus B_\epsilon({\bf p})$ and apply Green's theorem to $f(B')$. We then get
$$N={1\over2\pi}\int_{f(\partial B)}{\bf A}\cdot d{\bf w}={1\over2\pi}\int_{f(\partial B')}{\bf A}\cdot d{\bf w}+{1\over2\pi}\int_{f(\partial B_\epsilon)}{\bf A}\cdot d{\bf w}\ .$$
Since the first term on the right hand side vanishes we have
$$N={1\over2\pi}\int_{f(\partial B)}{\bf A}\cdot d{\bf w}={1\over2\pi}\int_{f(\partial B_\epsilon)}{\bf A}\cdot d{\bf w}\ .$$
Now $f(\partial B_\epsilon)$ is a tiny ellipse around ${\bf 0}$, and a suitable limiting argument should then prove that $N= {\rm sgn}\bigl(J_f({\bf z}_0)\bigr)$ in this case.

Comment: (+1) Incidentally, I'm guessing the new notation means $F(x_{0}, y_{0}) = (s_{0}, t_{0})$, so the condition "$F(x, y) \neq (s_{0}, t_{0})$ on the boundary" is automatic, and the boundary winds $\pm1$ times. Particularly, the question is in fact sensible, and you've answered it. :)

Comment: @Blatter. Can you clarify your methods?

Since circle $\partial B({\bf z}_0)$ is positively oriented, we know that the orientation of Jordan curve $f(\partial B({\bf z}_0))$ is ${\rm sgn}\bigl(J_f({\bf z}_0)\bigr)$, and if ${\bf 0}\in f(B)$, then the orientation of $f(\partial B_\epsilon ({\bf 0}))\subset f( B({\bf z_0}))$ is also ${\rm sgn}\bigl(J_f({\bf z}_0)\bigr)$.
If the vector field $\bf{A}$ is trivial, i.e. $${\bf A}(x,y)=\left({-y\over x^2+y^2}, \>{x\over x^2+y^2}\right)$$

Comment: it's easy to conclude from Green's theorem that $${1\over2\pi}\int_{f(\partial B_\epsilon (\bf 0))}{\bf A}(x,y)\cdot (dx,dy)={\rm sgn}\bigl(J_f({\bf z}_0)\bigr).$$
But, if the vector field $\bf{A}$ is not trivial, as $${\bf A}(f_1,f_2)=\left({-f_2 (x,y)\over f_1^2 (x,y)+f_2^2 (x,y)}, \>{f_1 (x,y)\over f_1^2(x,y)+f_2^2(x,y)}\right)$$
How can you calculate the integral $${1\over2\pi}\int_{f(\partial B_\epsilon (\bf 0))}{\bf A}(f_1,f_2)\cdot (df_1,df_2)=\space  ????.$$ Sorry if I stress this too much, but I really don't understand, and that calculation is at the heart of my original question.